# How to make Unreal save assets in 3-file style?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal

I'm trying to play around with some code to explore UE4 maps, but it assumes that every file is actually multiple files, with the asset accompanied by a `.uexp` file and optionally a `.ubulk` file.  When I save a map in Unreal Engine, though, it's all there together as one big `.umap`.

A bit of googling suggests that [this can be changed](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/587400/what-are-uexp-and-ubulk-files.html) by changing two config options in the project's engine.ini file, but when I change that, the map still saves as a single file, both for saving the file in-place and saving a copy of it elsewhere, even after completely closing and re-launching the editor.

What's the proper way to force the editor to save my map as 3 files rather than just the one?  (Using Unreal Editor 4.25.4, in case it matters.)